# In IE browsers dojo widgets not re sizing while zoom the IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, dijit.layout

i have the following URL http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/demo/appLayout.html and i will give the boarder layout , i implemented the same boarder layout in one of my project.

In IE i am getting problem with zoom.

If i change the zoom in IE, some part of the content is hiding. This is happening in IE only. It's not re-sizing properly.

The Following image is in IE with 100% zoom
[image]

The following image is with 125% zoom

[image]